# Nose generate dynamically test with decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose

I have dynamic amount of test so i want use for loop
I'd try something like:

```
from nose.tools import istest, nottest
from nose.tools import eq_
import nose
nose.run()
@istest
def test_1():
    for i in range(100):
        @istest
        def test_1_1():
            eq_(randint(1,1),1)



---------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

But nose display it like only one test. How can i improve it to 100 tests?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For data-driven tests in nose, check out [`nose_parameterized`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized/).

Example usage:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized

@parameterized.expand([(1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 4)])
def test_add(self, a, b, sum):
    self.assertEqual(sum, a + b)
```

Here, two tests will be generated by the runner.  It tests `1+1==2` and `2+2==4`.  The decorator is also compatible with other test runners such as `unittest`.

Comment: Thanks!
But for me still does not clear how to use it with "for" loop.

Comment: Because you don't use it with the for loop - that's not the interface.  Let the decorator do the loop for you, it's much nicer.